# Java how to embed variables in a callback object

Tags: java, interface, callback

I like to enclose a variable in my callback object.
Is there a way to do it?

My callback is an interface:

```
public interface AsyncOpCallback {
    public long opStartTime;
    public void operationCompleted(Object sender);
}
```

A variable an interface gives an error.
Is there another way?

I just need to check the opStartTime after the callback object is returned:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //some code
        AsyncOpCallback asyncOpCallback =
                new AsyncOpCallback() {
                    public void operationCompleted(Object sender) {
                        //some code
                        // check startTime after the call back is received
                    }
                };
        asyncOpCallback.opStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        expenseClassify.serverPost(asyncOpCallback);
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the class that implements `AsyncOpCallback`?

Comment: "*A variable an interface gives an error.*" What error? And give a usage example with how you want to use the interface - post code.

Comment: Jason, yes, I do have control over AsyncOpCallback.  It was written by someone else before in the project.  I can change it if the change does not cause a problem.
The problem is the variables that I like to attach to AsyncOpCallback object.